Optimal Odometry and Data Fusion Frequencies for Differential Drive Robot
I am in charge of developing control code for a commercial-level differential drive robot using industrial-grade motors. I have a few questions related to optimal and standard frequencies for wheel odometry and data fusion:
Optimal and Standard Frequency for Wheel Odometry:
What is the optimal and standard frequency for wheel odometry in tasks such as state estimation, localization and mapping?
I am using ROS 2 and ROS 2 control for this project.
Any insights or recommendations based on your experience would be greatly appreciated.
Filtered Odometry Data Frequency with IMU and EKF:
I am using an IMU with a rate of about 100 Hz and employing an Extended Kalman Filter (EKF) to fuse this data with the odometry data.
What would be a suitable frequency for the filtered odometry data?
Please provide any justification or reasoning behind the suggested frequency if possible.
Thank you for your assistance!
